# Is it possible to have more than one Organization within a single GCP tenant?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

so as to facilitate development within my company by different users using different primary account domains I need to create an organization for a tenant subdomain openedgepay.com.

Have tried all I know to create a new organization within GCP.

Comment: Try to rephrase your question. I don't understand what you are asking. Your comment "Have tried all I know to create a new organization within GCP.". Include what you tried, what you expected to happen and what errors resulted. Start with the documentation on how to create an organization. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

Comment: Most likely what you want are one organization and multiple projects.